# count results by name

Tags: php, mysql

I didn't really know how to title this but whatever..

I need this to display each pokemon that is in slot 0, but if the same pokemon comes up twice I want it to say 2 next to the image instead of adding another image to the display. Sorry I'm not the best at explaining things.

Here is what I have, I know it is a mess.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
?>
<div style="width: 20%; float: left;">
<?php
echo '<img src="pokemon/'.$row['type'] .''.$battle_get2['pic'].'" border=0>' ; 

$idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
$iddd = strip_tags($idd);

?>
```

This is how I ended up making it work, thank you for your help :)

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) number FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0') GROUP BY pokemon");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

?>
<div style="width: 20%; float: left;">
<?php
echo '<img src="pokemon/'.$row['type'] .''.$battle_get2['pic'].'" border=0>' ; 
if($row["number"] > 1) echo $row["number"] . " Pokemons";
$idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
$iddd = strip_tags($idd);

?>
```

Comment: oh my dear, why don't you go for a join in query? Firing two queries where only one is sufficient is bad programming

Comment: Use the Count function of mysql along with an if statement

Comment: I know I need to do that, but I'm not exactly sure where and how to do it in this situation. @ user986959

Comment: You should look into using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements instead of mysql_ functions they've been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your query and group by `pokemon` and additionally select `COUNT(*)`. Additionally you could use an inner join in your first query, so you don't have to do another query.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) number FROM user_pokemon up INNER JOIN pokemon p ON(up.pokemon = p.name) WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0') GROUP BY up.id
```

Whole PHP:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) number FROM user_pokemon up INNER JOIN pokemon p ON(up.pokemon = p.name) WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0') GROUP BY p.id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
?>
<div style="width: 20%; float: left;">
<?php
echo '<img src="pokemon/'.$row['type'] .''.$row['pic'].'" border=0>' ; 
if($row["number"] > 1) echo $row["number"] . " Pokemons";
$idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
$iddd = strip_tags($idd);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but even with this it's still displaying the pokemon image more than once.  Also where are you getting the row["number"] from?

Comment: @user1908445 Really? How do you identify the pokemons? Is there something more unique then their name? Could you show us please a description of your table. I added the `
count(*)` as number.

Comment: In the table pokemon, the pokemon would have the same id if they were the same, but nothing in the table user_pokemon would be the same other than the name

Comment: @user1908445 Well, that's bad table design. Change your tables so that the pokemons in the user_pokemon table will save the pokemon id instead of the name. I will try to update my answer so that it works with your current tables.

Comment: I also need the name for other things, but thanks I will soon update to include the id's aswell :) and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer. I don't have much hope that it works now becuase it didn't before. But the inner join works, doesn't it? (The picture is right displayed without querying a second time.)

Comment: Doesn't work :/ I don't wanna keep bothering you though, I'll just attempt to do it on my own :/

Comment: Okay, if you want to. If you have some more question or need more help don't hesitate to ask again.

Comment: I got it to work, I'll accept your answer since it helped me alot ;) Updating my question with the working code.